# How to target a single viewed post page on Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I want to add an HTML tag if the page viewed is a 'viewed post page'. 
For example, if I have a blog and I am viewing the list of posts - after I click on the post and see the whole text and see all the post - I want to echo an HTML text.

I tried using `if ( !is_single ){}`...

I tried using `if ( !is_single($post) ){}`..

I tried using `if ( !is_singular ){}`

The only thing I find on Google is how to target specific posts. 
I went through the conditional tags too: https://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags

I didn't find what I'm looking for.

Comment: Please be more specific. What tag do you want to add? Also are you aware that `if ( ! is_single() ) ` is the opposite of what you're trying to do? It will be true if you're on any page but a single post (of any type except attachment and page).

Comment: ok, So I have this plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/pinterest-pin-it-button-on-image-hover-and-post/ which I want it to be activated ONLY on blog post pages in my website.
I edited the pinterest-pin-It-button.php file and its not getting fixed. I tried several variations `is_single() && is page()` and `is_single() && is_singular`... nothing is working.

Comment: Dude, you can do that using the plugin's basic settings. See their screenshots: https://wordpress.org/plugins/pinterest-pin-it-button-on-image-hover-and-post/screenshots/